# Button positioning in axes (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an existing plot (axes) with many patches. And I wish to add a few Buttons to the **existing axes**. If I write the following code it makes the whole axes as the button i.e. click is detected everywhere on the axes.

```
# ax is the reference to axes containing many patches
bSend = Button(ax, 'send')
bSend.on_clicked(fu)
```

The [example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/buttons.html) given by matplotlib does not use the **existing axes** but uses a new axes (?)

```
# Create axes
axprev = plt.axes([0.7, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
axnext = plt.axes([0.81, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])

# Make Buttons of those axes.
bnext = Button(axnext, 'Next')
bnext.on_clicked(callback.next)
bprev = Button(axprev, 'Previous')
bprev.on_clicked(callback.prev)
```

Is there a way that I can position Button on the **existing axes**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `matplotlib.widgets.Button` lives in its own axes, which you need to supply via the first argument. So you need to create an axes somewhere.

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you may simply choose coordinates inside the axes,

```
button_ax = plt.axes([0.4, 0.5, 0.2, 0.075])  #posx, posy, width, height
Button(button_ax, 'Click me')
```

The coordinates here are in units of the figure width and height. Hence the button will be created at 40% of figure width, 50% of figure height and is 20% wide, 7.5% heigh.

[image]

Alternatively you may place the button axes relative to the subplot axes using `InsetPosition`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from  matplotlib.widgets import Button
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import InsetPosition

fig, ax= plt.subplots()

button_ax = plt.axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
ip = InsetPosition(ax, [0.4, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1]) #posx, posy, width, height
button_ax.set_axes_locator(ip)
Button(button_ax, 'Click me')

plt.show()
```

Here, the button is positioned at 40% of the axes width and 50% of its height, 20% of the axes width long, and 8% heigh.

[image]

Comment: Thanks you for such an elaborate answer! I thought there might be a way to add the Button to the **existing axes** and there isn't so I will go with the "1 Axes per Button" way. Thanks.

Comment: Think of it more as if the Button **is** the axes. You have one axes to plot to and another one which **is** the button. So what you do is turning an existing axes into a Button.

Comment: Sure. And on a second parse I see you have used `InsetPosition`, I like that. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to horizontally center the button with respect to the existing axis?