# Get Matplotlib axis spine position in relative screen coordinates?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Consider this example:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

freqs = np.arange(2, 20, 3)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.001)
s = np.sin(2*np.pi*freqs[0]*t)
l, = plt.plot(t, s, lw=2)

left, bottom, width, height = 0.2, 0.91, 0.09, 0.05
btn = Button(plt.axes([left, bottom, width, height]), "Hello!")

plt.show()
```

This produces:

[image]

How can I get the actual position of the left spine of the axis in screen coordinates (relative, from 0.0 to 1.0) - so that I could set `left` to it, and the button would align with the red line indicated on the screenshot?

Comment: You could get the position of the `ax` via  `bbox = ax.get_position()` and then use e.g. `left, bottom, width, height = bbox.x0, bbox.x1 - 0.01, 0.09, 0.05`.

Comment: See also [Button positioning in axes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47489873/button-positioning-in-axes-matplotlib)

Comment: @JohanC, care making this an answer? It is imho the best way and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @Mr.T  Your answer is fine.  Another option is to directly use [ax.inset_axes](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.inset_axes.html), which default uses the `ax.transAxes` transform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [InsetPosition helper class](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator.InsetPosition.html#mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator.InsetPosition) provided by mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import InsetPosition

freqs = np.arange(2, 20, 3)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.001)
s = np.sin(2*np.pi*freqs[0]*t)
l, = ax.plot(t, s, lw=2)

left, bottom, width, height = 0, 1.05, 0.09, 0.05
button_ax = plt.axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
ip = InsetPosition(ax, [left, bottom, width, height]) 
button_ax.set_axes_locator(ip)
btn = Button(button_ax, "Hello!")

plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]

As a side effect, the button size will change when resizing the window. Whether this is a wanted or unwanted effect is up to your judgment.

Comment: That same effect is easier with `ax.inset_axes([left, bottom, width, height])`

Answer (score 2):

I played around with the spline properties and I think I found what you need. If you `print(ax.spines['left']get_spine_transform())` you get

```
BlendedGenericTransform(
    BboxTransformTo(
        TransformedBbox(
            Bbox(x0=0.125, y0=0.20000000000000007, x1=0.9, y1=0.88),
            BboxTransformTo(
                TransformedBbox(
                    Bbox(x0=0.0, y0=0.0, x1=6.4, y1=4.8),
                    Affine2D().scale(100.0))))),
    CompositeGenericTransform(
        TransformWrapper(
            BlendedAffine2D(
                IdentityTransform(),
                IdentityTransform())),
        CompositeGenericTransform(
            BboxTransformFrom(
                TransformedBbox(
                    Bbox(x0=-0.04995, y0=-1.1, x1=1.04895, y1=1.1),
                    TransformWrapper(
                        BlendedAffine2D(
                            IdentityTransform(),
                            IdentityTransform())))),
            BboxTransformTo(
                TransformedBbox(
                    Bbox(x0=0.125, y0=0.20000000000000007, x1=0.9, y1=0.88),
                    BboxTransformTo(
                        TransformedBbox(
                            Bbox(x0=0.0, y0=0.0, x1=6.4, y1=4.8),
                            Affine2D().scale(100.0))))))))
```

It looks like 0.125 is the value you are looking for. I am not sure how the trnaform structure works with matplotlib,so I don't know how to actually get that value contians in

```
BlendedGenericTransform(
    BboxTransformTo(
        TransformedBbox(
            Bbox(
```

So this answer isn't quite complete, but hopefully a helpful starting point.